# How to use stream functions to collapse objects with same atributte name?

Tags: java, arraylist, filter, java-stream, reduce

Trying to learning how to use stream reduce() filter().

I have a list of Tag objects:

```
Public class Tag {
    Private String name;
    Private list<Occurrence> occurences;
    ...
}


Public class Occurrence{
    Private int number;
    Private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    ...
}
```

Then, I want to collapse occurrences from Tags with the same name, like:

```
{
"name" : "Delivered",
[
"number" : 1,
"timestamp" "",
...
]
[
"number" : 2,
"timestamp" "",
...
]
}
{
"name" : "Delivered",
[
"number" : 3,
"timestamp" "",
...
]
}
{
"name" : "bounced",
[
"number" : 1,
"timestamp" "",
...
]
}
```

When I read the json I get duplicate Tags "Delivered".

How can I use stream functions to get this List and collapse occurrences with the same tag name?

Comment: Please share your **attempt** and specify what are the problems you've encountered.

Comment: `reduce() filter() ` - it doesn't make sense to use these operations in such order. Your IDE will prompt you that if you'll try.

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at [ask] and take the tour. Also take a look at minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Rafael Piazza Try using the Collectors::groupingBy method to group Tags with the same name. Then map each group of Tags to a Tag where the occurrences for the Tag is the concatenation of the occurrences for the Tags in the group.